# Playing DASH-video on website depending on the size of the container (not the bandwidth)

Tags: html5-video, video.js, mpeg-dash, shaka

I have a video in different resolutions (1200x900, 800x600, 400x300, 200x150) and a DASH-manifest. I tried to embed the video on a responsive webpage using the shaka or video-js video-player. This works so far, but the video displayed is depending more on the bandwidth than the size of the container which is playing in, for example:

- Container size: 800x600, low bandwidth -> Playing the video 200x150 -> Ok
- Container size: 1200x900, high bandwidth -> Playing the video 1200x900 -> Ok
- Container size: 200x150, high bandwidth -> Playing the video 1200x900 -> Not ok, because it's not necessary

I want to prevent the last case because it increases my traffic and on some devices/browsers the downscaling of the video is really horrible.

This happens on shaka and video-js. How can I tell the video-player not to use a bigger video than the size of it's container? Or is there any other player which is able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to acheive this using those players, but dash.js will certainly do this using the player option `limitBitrateByPortal`.

The documentation is horrible, but search [http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-Settings.html#~AbrSettings__anchor](http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-Settings.html#%7EAbrSettings__anchor) for `limitBitrateByPortal`.

An example of how to use it is available at https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/latest/samples/advanced/settings.html.